# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported

Tags: angularjs

I have made a custom "angular component library". I call this library ACL

I am importing the library into another project. When I run

`ionic-app-scripts build`, it builds successfully

BUT, when I run

`ionic-app-scripts build --prod`

it gives me following error message. any one with any clue.

---

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported.
>
> Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol NgModule in C:/Monsenso-Source/administration/node_modules/@monsenso/components/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol WebModule in C:/Monsenso-Source/administration/node_modules/@monsenso/components/dist/web.module.d.ts, resolving symbol WebModule in C:/Monsenso-Source/administration/node_modules/@monsenso/components/dist/web.module.d.ts
>       at Error (native)
>       at syntaxError (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1550:34)
>       at simplifyInContext (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23870:23)
>       at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23882:13)
>       at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23331:41)
>       at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13883:70)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14473:60)
>       at addNgModule (C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23050:58)
>       at C:\Monsenso-Source\administration\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23061:14
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.

---

The same error is also coming, if I execute the following command:

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

**Code for the ACL**

**page-template-middle.component.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <!-- empty -->
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <!-- empty -->
            </ion-col>      
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>      
</ion-content>
```

**page-template-middle.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mon-page-template-middle',
    templateUrl: './page-template-middle.component.html'
})
export class PageTemplateMiddleComponent {

}
```

**web.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import {
    PageTemplateMiddleComponent
} from './components/page-template-middle/page-template-middle.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PageTemplateMiddleComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        PageTemplateMiddleComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        IonicModule
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})

export class WebModule {
}
```

**Code for the consumer project**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WebModule } from '@monsenso/components';

import { MyAppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    declarations: [
        MyAppComponent,
        HomePageComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        MyAppComponent,
        HomePageComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        WebModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyAppComponent)
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any statements about the code you're working on because you haven't pasted any in your question. But in general, this error relates to Angular's AOT compiler being unable to resolve argument "types" in anonymous functions that aren't exported from your module.

For example, let's say I have a factory function that I want to use to provide a service for use in some of my components.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: () => {
      return new MyService();
    },
  }],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

In that example you can see an anonymous (unnamed) function being used as my factory function. This will work fine if you're not compiling AOT, but will otherwise break.

To fix this, the function needs to be exported from your module ("module" in the Typescript sense).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

export function myServiceFactory() {
  return new MyService();
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: myServiceFactory,
  }],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

I can't say that your error is exactly related to your ACL Angular Module using a factory function. But the error you've pasted in your question is absolutely related to Angular not being able to statically analyze a function because it hasn't been exported.

Comment: I have added the code in the post above to get more help from you. Do you want me to share some other code too. Please let me know.

Really appreciate your time.
Thanks